# Switching Between PoE and Power Input of DC 8-36V

Tags: switches, dc, poe

I am Planning to use PoE+ PD in my design. I have a DC power input option other than PoE which will be in range of 8-36V DC. I am planning to use one PD module with Integrated DC-DC converter which will give me an output of 12V DC Via PoE. The DC input (8-36V) of my board is connected to a wide range input regulator (Buck) and it will give 5V output. From this 5V, I will be powering all the peripherals in the board. I am also planning to connect the 12V from PoE to the same regulator Input.
In the above situation, IF DC input alone is there, then board will work fine and PoE alone is there then also board will work fine. If Both DC input and PoE voltage is available to board, then it will get short the both rails. I want to add one switching mechanism to select the voltage source either from DC input or PoE. I will get Power detection signal from PoE PD module if Power is getting from the PoE.
Can anybody suggest one switching mechanism with below functions

1. When DC Input alone is there, Board will be powered from DC input
2. When PoE alone is there, Board will be powered from PoE
3. When Both PoE and DC input is there, it will be powered from DC input (PoE power path should be open)

Regards,
Shafeeq

Comment: What is "PD" in this question? What are the currents involved?

Comment: @Andyaka PD (Powered device) controller is an IC which will enable the power from PoE source. The current involved is 2.5A.

Comment: Which PD chip are you using (part number)? Some PDs provide a mechanism to accept either PoE or auxiliary DC power.